# how to use group_concat with group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT 
    O.OrderId,
    O.Number,
    (SELECT 
            CONCAT(A.Detail, ' ', C.Name, ' / ', Ci.Name)
        FROM
            kobiakinlar.Address AS A
                INNER JOIN
            County AS C ON C.CountyId = A.CountyId
                INNER JOIN
            City AS Ci ON C.CityId = Ci.CityId
        WHERE
            UserId = O.UserId) AS UserAddress,
    (SELECT 
            CASE
                    WHEN O.Status = 0 THEN 'Onay Bekliyor'
                    WHEN O.Status = 1 THEN 'Onaylandı'
                    WHEN O.Status = 2 THEN 'Reddedildi'
                END
        ) Status,
    O.Creation,
    (SELECT 
            CASE
                    WHEN O.IsDelivered = 0 THEN 'Teslim Edilmedi'
                    ELSE 'Teslim Edildi'
                END
        ) IsDelivered,
    SUM(T.Price) Price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(T.NAME) Products
FROM
    kobiakinlar.order O
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  
        P.Name, op.OrderId, op.Price
    FROM
        kobiakinlar.product P
    JOIN kobiakinlar.orderproduct op ON op.ProductId = P.productId
 ) T ON O.orderId = T.orderId
        INNER JOIN
    address A ON A.AddressId = O.AddressId
```

It returns:

[image]

But I want to try have this one:

[image]

What should I do? Do you have any suggestion for me?

Comment: There is no `group_by` in your SQL statement ?

Comment: @ManseUK, yes because, I put and it didn't work... And also I couldn't find where should I put my group by

Comment: give more details as to which columns you need to group etc. From the screenshot it cant be understood.

Comment: @nawfal, I need to group by with orderId...

Comment: Without seeing data its difficult. Are you so sure that records with order id = 5 and 8 exist in your db and that no `WHERE`/`JOIN` condition is chopping them off?

Comment: @nawfal, yes I m sure the records in db and any condition doesn't chopping them off. As you can see in first screeenshot, my query returns all products. But I want to see take the products by order.

Comment: @cagin what happens when you put a `group by o.orderid` at the last of the query?

Comment: @nawfal, nothing.. It s the same result with first screenshot

Comment: `INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  
        P.Name, op.OrderId, op.Price
    FROM
        kobiakinlar.product P
    JOIN kobiakinlar.orderproduct op ON op.ProductId = P.productId
 ) T ON O.orderId = T.orderId` or the JOIN on address beneath is chopping your data. ensure yourself. Try with left join also

Comment: I tried left join and it doesnt work.. The same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my quert with this:

```
    SELECT op.OrderId,
    O.Number,    
    SUM(op.Price) Price,
    (SELECT CONCAT(A.Detail, ' ',C.Name, ' / ', Ci.Name) FROM kobiakinlar.Address AS A
                INNER JOIN County AS C ON C.CountyId = A.CountyId
                INNER JOIN City AS Ci ON C.CityId = Ci.CityId
                WHERE UserId = O.UserId) AS UserAddress,
   ( SELECT CASE WHEN O.Status =0 THEN 'Onay Bekliyor'  WHEN O.Status =1 THEN 'Onaylandı' WHEN O.Status = 2 THEN 'Reddedildi' END) Status,
    O.Creation,
    ( SELECT CASE WHEN O.IsDelivered =0 THEN 'Teslim Edilmedi' ELSE 'Teslim Edildi' END) IsDelivered,
    group_concat(P.Name) Product
FROM
    kobiakinlar.product P
        JOIN
    kobiakinlar.orderproduct op ON op.ProductId = P.productId
        JOIN
    kobiakinlar.order O ON O.orderId = op.OrderId
   JOIN 
kobiakinlar.address A ON A.addressId = O.AddressId
GROUP BY op.OrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you want is:

```
group_concat(distinct t.name separator ',') as Products
```

Comment: it returns one row and it doesn't give all products.

Comment: In that case, your query needs a `group by` statement.  Something like `group by orderid, ordername`.